# Weaving Aspect into executable jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable, aspectj

I am trying to log all the method calls in a game that comes as an executable jar files.

I am using the command from the command line:

```
ajc -injars tetris.jar Tracing.aj -outjar tetris.jar...
```

After compiling the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
```

I am also an Eclipse user.

Answer (score 1):

Yoou need to add [`aspectjrt.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.12/aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar) to your CLASSPATH.

Since you said you are an Eclipse user: [How to Add JARs to Project Build Paths in Eclipse (Java)](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29) describes this in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

1) Class is not available in Java Classpath.

2) Any startup script is overriding Classpath environment variable.

As Tomasz Nurkiewicz said you have to add it to your ClassPath.

Comment: Hi Tomasz and other

Thanks for the reply. The aspectjrt.jar classpath is already set. Still I get the errors...

Is there any other alternatives?